# Batch file string modification

Tags: windows, string, batch-file

If I had the following code:

```
set alpha=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

What would I have to do to %alpha% in order to result in only a, b, c, . . ., z?

Comment: Isn't it already only `a, b, c, ..., z`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to access it via the position you need

```
set alpha=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
echo %alpha:~0,1%
echo %alpha:~1,1%
echo %alpha:~2,1%
echo %alpha:~25,1%
```

Explained at `set /?`

Comment: @Whef: Please take into account that it is possible (and is greatly encouraged) to formally [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer that has worked for you.

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't realize what that check was for.